# resample datetimeindex via prod() function changes NaN to 1

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, resampling

I am working with a rather large dataset. After applying the resample command in combination with the conversion method "prod" (multiplication), I realized that my NaN values were changed to 1, which is not what I intended. To give an example what happened:

```
# build random dataframe with one column containing NaN
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=7, freq='d')
df = pd.DataFrame(index = index, columns = ["Score 1", "Score 2", "Score 3"])

df["Score 1"] = np.random.randint(1,20,size=7)
df["Score 2"] = np.random.randint(1,20,size=7)
df["Score 3"] = [1, 2, 3, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN]
print(df)

            Score 1     Score 2     Score 3
2000-01-01  6            7          1.0
2000-01-02  2            15         2.0
2000-01-03  8            19         3.0
2000-01-04  14           19         NaN
2000-01-05  17           8          NaN
2000-01-06  15           6          NaN
2000-01-07  12           18         NaN
```

Now lets say I want to resample my Dataframe from a daily to a 3-day Frequency with using the "prod" conversion method. I do so by:

```
df.resample("3d").agg("prod")
print(df)

            Score 1     Score 2     Score 3
2000-01-01  96          1995        6.0
2000-01-04  3570        2052        1.0
2000-01-07  12            18        1.0
```

Looking at the column "Score 3", my NaN values suddenly changed to 1, which is a surprise for me. This means that when multiplying NaN with each other, I would get =1. Does anyone why exactly a multiplication of NaN's equals one and what I could do to keep the NaN value in case it is multiplicated with itself?

Thanks in advance, any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.prod` function ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html#pandas-dataframe-prod)) by default sets `NaN` to 1:

```
pd.Series([np.NaN, np.NaN]).prod()
# 1.0
```

You can circumvent this by setting the according keyword:

```
pd.Series([np.NaN, np.NaN]).prod(skipna=False)
# nan
```

In your case, you could apply that as

```
print(df)
            Score 1  Score 2  Score 3
2000-01-01       18       19      1.0
2000-01-02        9       18      2.0
2000-01-03       10        4      3.0
2000-01-04        4       15      4.0
2000-01-05       12        1      NaN
2000-01-06        1        3      NaN
2000-01-07        8        9      NaN

print(df.resample("3d").agg(pd.DataFrame.prod, skipna=False))
            Score 1  Score 2  Score 3
2000-01-01     1620     1368      6.0
2000-01-04       48       45      NaN
2000-01-07        8        9      NaN
```

Note that this will set all resampled time windows to `NaN` if the window contains at least one `NaN` value - I changed the example `df` slightly to show that. You can `apply` a `lambda` instead, checking if at least one element is not `NaN`:

```
print(df.resample("3d").apply(lambda x: x.prod() if any(x.notnull()) else np.nan))
            Score 1  Score 2  Score 3
2000-01-01     1620     1368      6.0
2000-01-04       48       45      4.0
2000-01-07        8        9      NaN
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. I overflew the pandas documentation and missed the skipna command. The approach with the lamda is exactly what I needed. But just out of curiosity, do you have an idea why the prod function interprets NaN * NaN as one? Is it just for easier handling when NaN values occur in a time series?

Comment: @Sanjo: I'd say this is because by default, the result should not be NaN if only one value of the Series is NaN